# Mac OSX EFI problems, urgent help needed!

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, efi

So, I recently did an update on OSX, booted my computer up and I discovered that I the update replaced my EFI boot rom and the SMC with the incorrect SMC, so now I can't use my battery and the computer is generally acting very strange.

I have looked all over the internet for some kind of answer on how to resolve this with no luck, or the solutions i have seen / found have been outdated and not appropriate for my Macbook Pro.

So essentially I have a Macbook Pro 13" late 2011 8,1 running OSX 10.9.5 the EFI and SMC for this is meant to be:

EFI MBP81.0047.2AB (2015-001)
SMC: 1.68f98 (SMC 1.5)

However, the SMC and EFI that I am seeing is this:

EFI: MBP81.0047.B2A (2015-001)
SMC: 1.68f99 (SMC 1.6)

Which is for the Macbook Pro 17" Early 2011 8,3.

Does anyone out there know how to resolve this I'm losing my mind over this since Apple refuse to tell me how to do it and the only option they are providing me with is a new Logic board, which we all know is not necessary.

I would genuinely appreciate a guide on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried an SMC reset?

Comment: I can't reset the SMC because the SMC is incorrect - this isn't as simple as just resetting the SMC or PRAM. I need to format the partition with the BIOs and install a new BIOs. However, finding this information on the internet is tough.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the following websites:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1823
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1474

Download and install the firmwares starting with the EFI. Here we are going to restart the same installation so we can run some diagnostics and hardware tests.

Also, two things should be explained before we can continue:
1) Mac OS X has no BIOS but essentially a proprietary version of EFI. EFI was developed by Intel back in the 90s and later a new set of specifications called UEFI were made. UEFI 2.xx was made and development continued under this forum founded offset branch. Apple took in EFI and developed their own versions off of it.
2) The boot processes is different than most computers. A piece of firmware called the BootRom starts the Power-On Self Test and then starts the EFI. The EFI chooses the default disk partition or allows you to choose it manually. After the partition is selected, the boot.efi boot loader then loads the kernel. Apple considers the I/O kit as a part of the kernel. So if the EFI improperly loads the kernel, then you could be having driver issues.

Now to go through a run a diagnostics test and hardware test. Fully power off and power on while pressing and holding the "d" key. This will either run diagnostics or a hardware test. I need you to follow the directions below for either one you booted into. Then do the same except power on pressing and holding "alt/option" and "d" at the same time. Again, reply back with what was found.

While in the hardware test: plug in the AC adapter, choose your language (skip if this doesn't appear), select "Perform extended testing", click the test button, reply any errors (there shouldn't be any) you found, reply everything you saw in the test, and exit after the test by pressing "Shutdown" or "Restart" at the bottom.

While in the diagnostic test: plug in the AC adapter, choose your language and press the "return/enter" key (skip if this doesn't appear), reply back any issues found, and exit after the test by pressing "Shutdown" or "Restart" at the bottom.

If no issues are found, restart and check the Boot ROM Version and SMC Version under " > About This Mac > Overview > System Report > Hardware" to see if it finally matches MBP81.0047.2AB and 1.68f98. Reply if they don't. Then go to Diagnostics under " > About This Mac > Overview > System Report > Hardware > Diagnostics", and there should be a Power On Self-Test and maybe some other tests. Reply any tests that have not passed.